# Vim regex range with current cursor position

Tags: regex, vim, range, substitution

To substitute, what's the proper range format for current cursor position to end of file?
I believe cursor is `.` and end of file will be `$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry if I'm misinterpreting, but if you want to do a replace from the current line until the end of the file, you can do:

```
:.,$ s/original/replace/g
```

As @PeterRincker mentions, the current line can be considered implicit, meaning that you can also use:

```
:,$ s/original/replace/g
```

To achieve the same result.

Comment: Easy enough, that's what I was looking for. Jumped the gun a little.
How would you format from current cursor to x more lines? Say, the next 99.
:.,99 s/o/r/g ?

Comment: @HenryDavid Yep, that's how I would do it :)

Comment: Don't forget that the current line can be assumed, so it can be dropped. `,$s/o/r/g`

Comment: @PeterRincker Very cool, did not know that - I'll update (and thanks for the tip!).

Answer (score 2):

You already know the right terms, and have the right ideas... why don't you just consult the built-in help; it's really fantastic.

```
:help :range
```

or `:help :s` will lead you to `:help [range]`.